# Rewrite Rules are not being picked up by the Server

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, xampp

I'm unsure why the **mod_rewrite.c** is not correctly pathing the link

**Example URL**

http://developer.prodev/dev_www_trunk/justink/public_html/search/manufacturer/hewlett-packard

**Rewrite Engine**

http://developer.prodev/dev_www_trunk/justink/public_html/search/index.php?advanced=0&manufacturer_rewrite=hewlett-packard

I have tested my rewrite rules on [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

[image: rewrite_result]

But this not the same result, I get within my **error_log.log** that was redirecting to *justink/search/manufacturer/...* (**public_html** fails to fall within rewrite).

```
# dev_www_trunk/justink/public_html/search/manufacturer/hewlett-packard 
RewriteRule ^(dev_[^/]*)/justink/public_html/search/manufacturer/?(.*)$ /$1/justink/public_html/search/index.php?advanced=0&manufacturer_rewrite=$2%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logs:

```
'^(dev_[^/]*)/justink/public_html/search/manufacturer/?(.*)$' to uri 'search/manufacturer/hewlett-packard'
```

You have to much prefix information in your regex. As you can see the URL provided to your regex is only

```
'search/manufacturer/hewlett-packard'
```

I believe you also want to redirect to a new HTTP location and not to a file, so that your `mod_php` or `php-fpm` interpret your redirected request:

```
RewriteRule /search/manufacturer/?(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/search/index.php?advanced=0&manufacturer_rewrite=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: I would like the REQUEST to work on `localhost` (the domain `developer.prodev` is `hosts` re-path). Is there anyway you could improve the answer, so that the regex works on both paths?

Comment: Thanks Martin, I didn't end up using the Rewrite Rules, you set out in the answer.. (But your answer, did set me on a better path). Now the website, I was designing them for, has slightly better [seo](http://www.justink.co.nz/search/manufacturer/hewlett-packard.php).